# Why can't I import Glibc in a Swift Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: swift, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04, swift-for-tensorflow, cinterop

When I execute:

```
import Glibc
```

as the first line in my notebook running on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 GCE VM, I get the following error message:

```
expression failed to parse, unknown error
```

Answer (score 0):

Install missing libc dependency:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```